# Really weird situation with Swap that refuses to work

Tags: 12.04, boot, 64-bit, hibernate, swap

So I decide to move my Swap partition to another HDD to make hibernation more fast, I create a partition with a liveUSB, do swapon, and then hibernate just disappears

I go into the terminal, reactivate hibernate (so the button shows) for some reason the swap wasn't "on" so I do swapon again.

Still not working.

I go back to the terminal and edit the file with the UUID of the new swap partition.

The partition shows as swap on gparted, it's on, the file has the right UUID, even the task manager shows a swap area of 10GB, and there is a hibernate button on the shutdown window. EDIT: it's even using the swap for VM, 7.4% to be precise.

But it-wont-hibernate!

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your swap space to `/etc/fstab`? If not, add it like so:

```
/[your swap path here] swap swap defaults 0 0
```

When added to fstab, try rebooting. Anything in `fstab` is mounted automatically on boot, so after that, verify that swap is there with

```
free -m
```

More info [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/) (although this example focuses on creating a swap *file*) :)

Comment: I got a line that says [UUID]  none            swap    sw              0       0    do I edit that or create a new line?

Comment: Just asking to be sure

Comment: It's hard to know for sure but the old UUID might be to your old swap. Just add another one, won't do any damage to have both (the first one will just consistently fail and move on). If you get it to work, you can try cutting out that line if you suspect it to be old.

Comment: The current UUID is the new one

Comment: ...and? I'm still waiting for your result, what does `free -m` say?

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3954       3842        112          0         11        100
-/+ buffers/cache:       3730        224
Swap:        10239       1303       8936
But hibernate still doesn't works